# Screenshot in landscape using Qt

Tags: qt, nokia

I am using the following code to take screenshot in a Nokia device using Qt

```
QDesktopWidget *w = QApplication::desktop();
if (w)
{
        QRect r = w->screenGeometry();
        originalPixmap = QPixmap::grabWindow(w->winId(),0,0,r.width(), r.height());

}
originalPixmap.save(folder_path, format.toAscii().constData());
```

The code is working fine for portrait orientation. When I tilt the device to landscape, the captured image contains only half the width of the screen. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab the whole window anyway, have you tried just using `originalPixmap = QPixmap::grabWindow(w->winId())`? Leaving out the size parameters [should use the size of the whole window automatically](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qpixmap.html#grabWindow).

Comment: solved this, I have fixed my app to work only in portrait, now changed it to work both ways and screenshots are fine now. Thanks